# Get Element from XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, web-scraping

I want to get the elements from a XML that can be fetched from a URL.

I have written the following code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1568219/000156821918000001/primary_doc.xml'
    req = ulib.Request(url)
    primaryXML = ulib.urlopen(req)
    xmlData = primaryXML.read()
    content = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
```

The XML that is available is

```
<edgarSubmission xmlns="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/thirteenffiler" xmlns:com="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/common">
<headerData>
<submissionType>13F-HR</submissionType>
<filerInfo>
<liveTestFlag>LIVE</liveTestFlag>
<flags>
<confirmingCopyFlag>false</confirmingCopyFlag>
<returnCopyFlag>false</returnCopyFlag>
<overrideInternetFlag>false</overrideInternetFlag>
</flags>
<filer>
<credentials>
<cik>0001568219</cik>
<ccc>XXXXXXXX</ccc>
</credentials>
</filer>
<periodOfReport>12-31-2017</periodOfReport>
</filerInfo>
</headerData>
<formData>
<coverPage>
<reportCalendarOrQuarter>12-31-2017</reportCalendarOrQuarter>
<filingManager>
<name>TD Ameritrade Trust Co</name>
<address>
<com:street1>PO BOX 17748</com:street1>
<com:city>DENVER</com:city>
<com:stateOrCountry>CO</com:stateOrCountry>
<com:zipCode>80217-0748</com:zipCode>
</address>
</filingManager>
<reportType>13F HOLDINGS REPORT</reportType>
<form13FFileNumber>028-15163</form13FFileNumber>
<provideInfoForInstruction5>N</provideInfoForInstruction5>
</coverPage>
<signatureBlock>
<name>Erik Hunt</name>
<title>Senior Analyst</title>
<phone>303-294-5311</phone>
<signature>Erik Hunt</signature>
<city>Denver</city>
<stateOrCountry>CO</stateOrCountry>
<signatureDate>02-26-2018</signatureDate>
</signatureBlock>
<summaryPage>
<otherIncludedManagersCount>0</otherIncludedManagersCount>
<tableEntryTotal>20</tableEntryTotal>
<tableValueTotal>268468</tableValueTotal>
<isConfidentialOmitted>false</isConfidentialOmitted>
</summaryPage>
</formData>
</edgarSubmission>
```

I want to get the value of submissionType

When I try

```
content.find("edgarSubmission/headerData/submissionType")
```

I dont get any result. I want to get 13F-HR

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please note that the XML in the question is not correctly formed/indented. Please see the actual URL for the correct hierarchy of the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. If `13F-HR` is your only requirement to fetch, the script should do that.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

res = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1568219/000156821918000001/primary_doc.xml")
tree = fromstring(res.content)
item = tree.cssselect("submissionType")[0].text
print(item)
```

OR

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

res = urlopen("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1568219/000156821918000001/primary_doc.xml")
tree = fromstring(res.read())
item = tree.cssselect("submissionType")[0].text
print(item)
```

Output:

```
13F-HR
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to also understand how to make it work with regular xml parsing. Also what I am doing wrong. Any ideas ? Thanks for the solution though.

Comment: I didn't find any such line `how to make it work with regular xml parsing` in your question as you just erected.

Comment: So ? I am looking to learn as well as to what is going wrong. If you dont know - please let me know.

Comment: As in the last sentence, I state - "please explain what I am doing wrong" -- can you please ?

Comment: Add the full script you tried with. Your script is wrongly indented and what is `ulib`?

Comment: Css select is fine. I can operate with this. Thanks for the help.